# Raphael not running callback parameter

Tags: javascript, callback, raphael, incompatibility, yepnope

After loading Raphael with yepnope, I try to run Raphael with the callback parameter-- as per the following section:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael

Example code:

```
    yepnope({
        load: 'lib/raphael.js',
        complete: function () {
            Raphael('idm', 10, 10, function () {alert('callback run!')});
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, the callback doesn't run in Firefox and IE. It does run in Chrome. What can I do to make the callback run in all browsers?

Comment: on FireFox, check out the JS console on FireBug, or the included web console, any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. When loading async script by YepNope, callback function don't not run in IE 8 ,9. But firefox and chrome are fine. So I decide to include js file by 'script' tag. Though it make  loading time is slower.

Comment: The other option is to run your code procedurally (i.e., put your code on the next line, instead of in the callback.)

This allows you to use YepNope for Raphael. Just be sure to use YepNope's 'complete' method.